# Isn't it guaranteed that a parallel stream derived from a list will always behave like its sequential counterpart giving the same, predictable output?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

The following code prints true for 100 times:

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
   String s2 = Arrays.asList("A", "E", "I", "O", "U").parallelStream().reduce("x", String::concat, String::concat);
   System.out.println("xAxExIxOxU".equals(s2));
}
```

Granted, 100 times is not a guarantee. But doesn't it seem though that even if the identity used here does not meet the requirement "...for all u, combiner.apply(identity, u) is equal to u" per the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html), we can still say that a parallel stream derived from a list or any other inherently ordered structure will behave just like a sequential stream in reduce()  returning the same output?

Comment: Why do you think you can say that? The result is entirely different from a sequential stream. It happens to be repeatable with parallel stream in your environment because you have more CPU cores than stream elements. But that's still not reliable. And, as said, entirely different from a sequential stream.

Comment: [On larger datasets, this is not true](https://tio.run/##zVE9TwMxDN3zK55uQHccpDAfRWJgAwmpIzD42rSk5D4aO4WC@tuLry0bE2LAi7/i5/ecJa3pfDl73fmm76JgqblN4oM9rYyZBmLGPfkWn8b0qQ5@ChYSdevOz9BoK59I9O3i8RkUF1zgc3cogKnpg8MYGaHGFDM4zLHACzyWeEVAgxYdeqwQwRAkrPGGd2zwkVXmzrNcHbCuETRRqJsYacOWeGjmhw2W@@Alz56euMyKojLH/V2SytRdFxy1oBBuV4mCYkhMTsWNRpi4VXKteC2zREcNm3kXc9@KUhzjolJ3hcuLIShLlWagprjaHAjZw1Re2OhmaeryLDvL6awuzq@pzJCVdWGViz6o9pPfJE7GimHdEPJRhL7YmsmGxTV2aPYqQUKbf48UFZTww1DdC4CfD3Do5pAXh@g4BWH9Aoc9ruo7/VsbGfPjER8oat399oT9cXzyb0@52253Xw)

Comment: If you have a different question than the one you originally asked, you should roll back the question to the now-answered original state, and ask the other question separately. "Chameleon questions" -- changing when answered -- are unfair to those who go to the effort to answer them in their original state.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good point! I edited it again trying to reflect the original question as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Javadoc for the `Stream.reduce` function with an identity argument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) says:

> The identity value must be an identity for the accumulator function.
>   This means that for all t, accumulator.apply(identity, t) is equal to
>   t.

Which is clearly not the case here - `"x".concat(anything)` doesn't equal `anything`. The only valid identity value here is `""`.

If you had tested the premise of the *title* of your question - by seeing what a non-parallel operation returns - you'd see that the answer to your title is "no" - because a non-parallel stream returns `"xAEIOU"` for your reduce operation.

If you change the identity value from `"x"` to `""`, then the answer would be "yes, there is such a guarantee, as your reduce function is **associative** and the constraints on the identity value are also satisfied."

Even with your modified title, the answer is clear:

You are breaking the contract of the `reduce` function by providing, as the identity value, a value that is not an identity value for your reduce function. As such, since you are breaking the contract of the `reduce` methods, all guarantees are off.

It's easy to create a case where it doesn't hold; just make your list larger like Holger already pointed out:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    list.add("A");
}
String s2 = list.parallelStream().reduce("x", String::concat, String::concat);
System.out.println(s2);
if (s2.length() != list.size() * 2) {
    System.out.println("Bad s2 size");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the problem in my title. I have revised it to better reflect my puzzlement.

Comment: @TreefishZhang now you have asked a very different question. I wasn't pointing out any problem in your title, I was answering the question that you originally asked.

Comment: The problem in the original title was that it did not match the sample code given in the body of the question.